# Is it possible to change playback speed of only one MovieClip without changing framerate using only AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, movieclip, flvplayback, frame-rate

Is it possible to change playback speed of only one MovieClip without changing framerate using only AS3? I mean, is there any function/property in MovieClip or somewhere that changes the playback speed of ONLY one MovieClip at the same time not affecting general framerate? Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tween classes of flash as well as there is another external classes for tweening objects which i recommend for you here it is link for [that](http://www.greensock.com/v11/)

Answer (score 2):

using `Timer` `class` u can do that.

but, Timer will vary depends on the swf's framrate or available memory and other factors.

for more [click here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)